# Why is it illegal to branch into or out of a parallel region?

Tags: openmp

I have just started to learn parallel programming with OpenMP, with the [OpenMP tutorial by Blaise Barney at Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP). There, in many places it is specified that it is illegal to branch into or out of a parallel region, but I do not have, at least, a little clue why.

If someone can explain why that is so, it will be really helpful to be comfortable with OpenMP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parallel region will require some set-up and take-down to operate correctly. For example, entering the region may require spawning threads, while exiting may require synchronization. The compiler generates the material "in the middle" of the parallel region with the assumption that this set-up and take-down have occurred.

If you were to branch into a parallel region, then you've skipped the set-up and it's hard to say what would actually happen. I.e., where would the threads be? Would you even be in the function call that, e.g., pthread was supposed to invoke for you?

And if you were to branch out, would you even be in the non-parallel section of your code? What if *all* the threads were to execute this section? What about race conditions?

So because the compiler must make assumptions of *your* behavior to generate parallel code correctly, *you* would do well to honor those assumptions.